# How does this Array.prototype.find() work?

Tags: javascript

What I do not understand is the function and its parameter `fruit`, because it's not being passed anything.

```
var inventory = [
  {name: 'apples', quantity: 2},
  {name: 'bananas', quantity: 0},
  {name: 'cherries', quantity: 5}
];

function findCherries(fruit) { 
  return fruit.name === 'cherries';
}

console.log(inventory.find(findCherries));
```

Comment: `findCherries` is being called for each element in the array by the `find` method. You can get a look "under-the-hood" on MDN, where they have a polyfill for this function: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find#Polyfill

Comment: `find` accepts a `function` as an argument.

Comment: documentation and [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find#Polyfill) for your education pleasure

Answer (score 2):

> ...because it's not being passed anything.

It *is* being passed something, you just don't see the code doing it, which is *inside* the `Array.prototype.find` method's code. Remember, this line:

```
console.log(inventory.find(findCherries));
```

...passes the *value* of `findCherries` (a function reference) into `find`, it doesn't *call* `findCherries`. `find` does that, once for each entry in the array, supplying three arguments (only one of which `findCherries` uses). The first of those arguments is the array entry for that call.

The full polyfill for `Array.prototype.find` makes for tricky reading, so let's do something similar but simpler so you can see the calls:

```
// A bit like Array.prototype.find, but **not** the same; much simplified
function fakeFind(callback) {
  for (var index = 0; index < this.length; ++index) {
    var entry = this[index];
    //  vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv---- This is where findCherries is called
    if (callback(entry, index, this)) {
      return entry;
    }
  }
  return undefined;
}
```

Live copy:

```js
// A bit like Array.prototype.find, but **not** the same; much simplified
function fakeFind(callback) {
  for (var index = 0; index < this.length; ++index) {
    var entry = this[index];
    //  vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv---- This is where findCherries is called
    if (callback(entry, index, this)) {
      return entry;
    }
  }
  return undefined;
}
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, "fakeFind", {
  value: fakeFind
});
var inventory = [
  {name: 'apples', quantity: 2},
  {name: 'bananas', quantity: 0},
  {name: 'cherries', quantity: 5}
];

function findCherries(fruit) { 
  return fruit.name === 'cherries';
}

console.log(inventory.fakeFind(findCherries));
```

Comment: I think I understand, the callback function findCherries is being called for each element of the array and each time element is being stored in the variable fruit.

Comment: @lana: Yes. [Technically `fruit` isn't a variable (it's an "argument"), but it behaves the same way in `findCherries` and the difference doesn't matter for what we're talking about.]

Answer (score 0):

If you expand the function so that it uses an anonymous function, it kind of makes more sense..

If you look at the code snippet below, it kind of explains it a bit more..

```js
var inventory = [
{name: 'apples', quantity: 2},
{name: 'bananas', quantity: 0},
{name: 'cherries', quantity: 5}
];

function findCherries(fruit) { 
  return fruit.name === 'cherries';
}

//this kind of does the same, apart from the extra anonymous function
//but here you can see this `item` that's getting passed
console.log(inventory.find(
  function (item) { return findCherries(item); }
));

//because in the above the anonymous function has the same
//signature, it's made redunant, so we may as well
//call findCherries direct..
console.log(inventory.find(findCherries));
```

Answer (score 0):

> The find() method returns a value in the array, if an element in the
>   array satisfies the provided testing function. Otherwise undefined is
>   returned. [Array.prototype.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

In your code snippet `fruit` is an item from your original array, i its value is an item in your array.`findCherries` will be compare  each element in your array for a match with property `name` (this is the provided testing function).

Your `findCherries` callback will be executed on each value in the array. When a match is found a result is returned.

Answer (score 0):

Implementation of Array find method.

```js
Array.prototype.MyFind = function(callback) {
  for (let i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    if(callback(this[i])){
      return this[i];
    }
  }
}

const array1 = [5, 12, 8, 130, 44];

const found = array1.find(element => element > 10 & element > 30 & element < 50);

console.log(found);
```